Should I pass viewmodel or state to compose component?
I have a compose component which fills the whole fragment. ViewModel has some items as a state to populate in the screen. Should I pass the viewmodel or only state as a parameter to composable function?

viewmodel at the highest composable. pass values that are required to child composable. So if a param or state changes only that child composable will recompose. testing and previews become easier as suggested as well

You should pass the state and not the viewmodel to the composable.
Passing the viewmodel directly to the composable would:

Complicate Isolated UI tests as you need to create an instance of the viewmodel if you did:
@Composable
fun MainScreen(viewmodel: MyViewModel){}

Mess up Previews on Android Studio as it does not know how to generate a viewmodel to display the preview.


You should pass the state in the
NavHost
composable(route = "Home"){
     val viewmodel = hiltViewModel<MainViewModel>()
     val state = viewModel.state
     MainScreen(state = state)
}

Or Fragment
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewmodel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    override fun onCreateView() {
        setContent {
            MainScreen(viewModel.state)
        }
    }
}

With the composable like
@Composable
fun MainScreen(state: ViewState)

Then you can preview
@Preview
@Composable
fun MainScreenPreview(){
    MainScreen(ViewState(title = "Page Title"))
}


Good answer! One note though, I would argue that it is also acceptable to pass a ViewModel to the top-level Composable of a screen, and then from there pass only the values and callbacks further down to the children. This helps to keep your NavHost a little bit cleaner.
